# Some buttons aren't working on mobile

Tags: bug, status-norepro

Certain features on the site don't seem to work on mobile (I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S4, chrome browser).

I can't open my notifications dropdown (the dropdown when there is new activity on my questions).

Also I can't seem to do upvotes or down votes.

Thought I should bring this up in case the site moderators were not aware.

Comment: I should add, they work fine on Stack Overflow, just not on Astronomy stack.

Comment: This has little to do with site moderators as you mention in your question. It is a matter of website development that isn't in the hands of moderators, all they can do is forward it to those that can do something about it. But if it's only related to this particular website, then I should mention that developers do read metas of sites for bug reports, like your question is tagged with, so no migration to [meta.se] is needed, unless it actually repeats on all [se] websites.

Answer (score 2):

All the stuff you mentioned that does not work is something that requires Javascript. The simplest explanation would be that for some reason the JS on your mobile browser got corrupted somehow.

So I'd try to clear the browser cache and maybe even restart the phone (I've experience some similar wierd JS issues with an older version of Cyanogenmod that were fixed by restarting).